# UISearchController not showing

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uisearchcontroller

I am working on Swift 3.1, I want a simple search functionality where the search results will show in a popOver manner below the search bar. This is a native offering and should be available using UISearchController. But even after my repeated trials, I could not achieve this. Am I missing something?

I have mentioned the resultsController. Implemented the required delegates and even the data us fed to it. But still its not shown.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Code:

```
func initiateView() {
    resultsController = ResultsController()
    resultsController.table.dataSource   =   self

    searchController   =   UISearchController.init(searchResultsController: resultsController)
    self.view.addSubview(searchController.searchBar)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater   =   self

    searchController.delegate = self
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false // default is YES
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self    // so we can monitor text changes + others
    definesPresentationContext = true


    feedTable   =   UITableView()
    feedTable.delegate  =   self
    feedTable.dataSource    =   self
    feedTable.separatorStyle    =   .singleLineEtched
    feedTable.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "SomeCell")
    self.view.addSubview(feedTable)


    feedTable.pinToSuperview([.Left, .Right, .Bottom])
    feedTable.pinToSuperviewTop(withInset: 50, priority: 100)
}


func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController)
{
    if let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text{
        let resultsController = searchController.searchResultsController as! ResultsController
        resultsController.resultsArray  =   feedArray.filter({$0 .contains(searchString)})
        resultsController.table.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: you are adding the search controller to subview but you dont set a frame or autolayout it :/

Comment: Shouldn't it automatically show just below the searchBar?

Comment: @AmitGupta, what exactly you need embed search bar in tableview or something else ?

Comment: Search bar is in a view and it searches a tableView below it. The search results needs to be shown in a impromptu temporary view just below search bar.